# How to generate an Intent that jumps into a specific short message conversation?

Tags: android, sms, android-intent

I would like to create an Intent that opens the messages application in a specific conversation.

If a short message notification is clicked Logcat reveals the following:

```
INFO/ActivityManager(31909): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://mms-sms/conversations/3 flg=0x34000000 cmp=com.android.mms/.ui.ConversationList bnds=[0,586][600,682] }
```

This brought me a little bit further using `content://mms-sms/conversations/3` as the data starts up the messages app in the correct conversation. I now only need to find out which conversation a message belongs to.

Comment: There is probably no documented way to do this. And how do you know the user has and or/wants to use that app?

Comment: I set the mms-sms stuff as the data only. If there is another sms app on the phone it could also listen for this intent and start the correct activity. The sms api is sadly not officially documented therefore I couldn't find a better way until now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to explore Android sources, specifically look into SMS/MMS ContentProvider sources. In the end all we know that SMS/MMS stored somewhere in SQLite database and ContentProvider is just way accessing to SQL tables through forming specific Uri string. In your case Uri string is:

> content://mms-sms/conversations/3
>   flg=0x34000000
>   cmp=com.android.mms/.ui.ConversationList
>   bnds=[0,586][600,682]

So you need to understand how this string parsed into normal data query. I believe it can be found in Android sources.